# JDBCBatchItemWriter not receiving the List for batch update

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm a new bee to spring batch. My requirement is to fetch records from a DB table, process them(each record can be processed independently so i'm partitioning and using a task executor) and then update the status column in the same table based on processing status.

Simplified version of my code is below.

**Item Reader** (My custom column partitioner will decide the min & max value below):

```
<bean name="databaseReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                select id,user_login,user_pass,age from users where id >= #{stepExecutionContext['minValue']} and id <= #{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.springapp.batch.UserRowMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

**Item Processor:**

```
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.springapp.batch.UserItemProcessor" scope="step"/>
....

public class UserItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Users, Users>
{

    @Override
    public Users process(Users users) throws Exception {
        // do some processing here..
        //update users status
        //users.setStatus(users.getId() + ": Processed by :" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Processed at :" + new GregorianCalendar().getTime().toString());
        //System.out.println("Processing user :" + users + " :" +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return users;
    }
}
```

**Item Writer:**

```
<bean id="databaseWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
            update users set status = :status where id= :id
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Step configuration:**

```
<batch:job id="usersJob">
    <batch:step id="stepOne">
        <batch:partition step="worker" partitioner="myColumnRangepartitioner" handler="partitionHandler" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="worker" >
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="databaseReader" writer="databaseWriter" commit-interval="5" processor="itemProcessor" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="asyncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
<bean id="partitionHandler" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler" scope="step">
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="asyncTaskExecutor"/>
    <property name="step" ref="worker" />
    <property name="gridSize" value="3" />
</bean>
```

Since i have specified the commit interval as 5 my understanding is that when 5 items are processed by a partition, it will call JDBCItemWriter with a List of 5 Users object to perform a batch JDBC update. However with the current setup, i'm receiving 1 User object at a time during batch update.

Is my understanding above correct or am i missing any step/configuration ?

Note: I'm using HSQL file based database for testing.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:C://users.txt"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Comment: How are you confirming that your writer is receiving only one item?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was debugging the code and added a break point on JDBCBatchitemWriter.write() method. i received the list with 1 User object at a time.